# How to handle serialization of Guid values in GraphQL using HotChocolate.AspNetCore? Id field being returned as base64 encoded string instead of Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am using version 12.16.0 and I am facing an issue with the Id field being returned as base64 encoded string instead of Guid. Is there a way to configure a custom serializer or scalar type for Guid values in the schema?

The ID is stored as a Guid in my database, but when queried through GraphQL, it is returned as a base64 encoded string. I want to customize the serialization so that the ID is returned as a Guid instead. I am using the HotChocolate library version 12.16.0, but I have not been able to find a solution that works. I was expecting to find a way to customize the serialization of the ID field so that it is returned as a Guid, but I have not been able to find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

How does your base64 encoded string look like? I use [this example](https://github.com/ajayhit/Asp.netCoreGraphQL) for testing, adding a column of Guid attribute values to the model and the corresponding database.

When I query the value of Guid from database using GraphQL, it is a string (The original Guid value removes "-"):

[image]

[image]

For this, you can specify `UuidType` to format. To change the default format we have to register the `UuidType` with the specifier on the schema:

```
services
   .AddGraphQLServer()
   .AddType(new UuidType('D'));
```

Test Result:

[image]

For the serialization format supported by `Uuid` scalar, you can refer to [this link](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/scalars#uuid-type).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: in the example (https://github.com/ajayhit/Asp.netCoreGraphQL) from you relay ploicy is not allowed. I have this problem at the [GraphQL Workshop] (https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop) from ChilliCream; and I have opened a [issue] (https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop/issues/105)

Comment: useful links:  - https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v10/schema/relay  - https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/relay -https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/relay#global-identifiers